# R feather package compilation error (g++) on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, r, gcc, freebsd, feather

I am trying to install the `feather` package on FreeBSD machine and it crashes due to the following error: `error: 'snprintf' was not declared in this scope`. `g++` is used for compilation.

Any hint on how to deal with this problem will be much appreciated.

Below is the full installation log.

```
* installing *source* package ‘feather’ ...
** package ‘feather’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Platform is little endian. Good.
** libs
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather-read.cpp -o feather-read.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather-types.cpp -o feather-types.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather-write.cpp -o feather-write.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/buffer.cc -o feather/buffer.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/feather-c.cc -o feather/feather-c.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/io.cc -o feather/io.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/metadata.cc -o feather/metadata.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/reader.cc -o feather/reader.o
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -DLIBICONV_PLUG -I/usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -DLIBICONV_PLUG -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLIBICONV_PLUG -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc5 -isystem /usr/local/include -c feather/status.cc -o feather/status.o
feather/status.cc: In member function 'std::__cxx11::string feather::Status::ToString() const':
feather/status.cc:52:52: error: 'snprintf' was not declared in this scope
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), " (error %d)", posix);
                                                ^
gmake: *** [/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:164: feather/status.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘feather’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/library/feather’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp26mAsU/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("feather") :
installation of package ‘feather’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I had to look up `snprintf` ...for a moment I thought it was just a typo. According to [this](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/snprintf-with-g-std-c-98-error-snprintf-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-td27135.html), you may need to change your `Makeconf` to suit compiling this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in file `feather/status.cc`. Try opening it and adding `#include <cstdio>` line to includes list at the top of it.

Comment: Ok, your solution works and the authors already applied a [patch](https://github.com/wesm/feather/pull/317) to the source code to deal with this issue on FreeBSD. Hence, I accept the answer. Thanks!